# Mac OS: How can I run a Cocoa application from within another Cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

I've written an Objective C runtime debugging tool (in Swift) to help me in the development of another application. Currently, this tool is a standalone Cocoa application that launches normally, with it's own instance of the Objective C runtime, so it's not of much use.

I would like to modify it so that it can be opened from a method call in a target application, and so that *uses the target application's runtime*. This requirement precludes the use of solutions I found which depend on `NSTask` to start a brand new process.

How can I achieve this?

Edit:

My debugging tool is a GUI application. Normally, it starts up via a call to `NSAppliationMain` from the `main` function. This sets up the application instance from the main bundle's `info.plist` file. Clearly this won't work when trying to call `NSApplicationMain` from within another application's code, as the `info.plist` of the main bundle is that of the target application, and not the debugged application.

So to paraphrase: How can I manually start up my application from its main nib file, opening its window, menu bar, etc. from within a target application?

Comment: Can you make it a shared library (framework)?

Comment: @MartinR I sure can, but I dont know how to properly start up the application if I did

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475476/load-a-mac-binary-as-a-dynamic-library) might help.

Comment: @CRD I don't need to load the library at runtime. I'm okay with having it be a statically linked shared library or framework. My issue is that I don't know how to initiate the "start up" process to load the application from there onwards

Comment: I read "I would like to modify it so that it can be opened from a method call in a target application" meant the target application was already running, or how else could it open your code from a method call? Maybe someone else can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @CRD I'm okay with needing to put in a call to manually start the application, and recompiling/rerunning the target application, at least for now.

Comment: @MartinR's comment made sense to me, given it did answer your question I thought dynamic linking might be what you sought, I was wrong (did you consider it could be your debugger calling `dlopen` on the target or vice-versa?) Given it seems two people haven't understood your issue you might want to consider editing your question to elaborate and then someone else might be able to help you. HTH

Comment: @CRD packing my debugging tool into a library will let my target application have access to the source of my debugging tool. I could either link it statically, or dynamically at runtime. I know how to do that, and that isnt the issue.

Comment: @CRD Given that my target application already has access to my debugging tool's code, in one way or another, how can I open my debugging tool (it's main window, menu bar, etc.?). I'm essentially asking how I can launch a cocoa application without having a main function to call NSApplication. NSApplication uses the main bundle's info.plist for determining the main nib, principal class, etc. idk how to launch my application without those being set in the usual manner. That's where I need help

Answer (score 1):

One last guess (after comments) and in rough outline only:

Step 1: Load your windows from their own NIB

Windows do not need to be loaded at startup from the main NIB, there are methods to load them programmatically as needed. E.g. look in `NSWindowController` (load a single window) and `NSBundle` (load a whole NIB-full of things).

Step 1B: Dynamically add menus/menu items

If you wish to have menu items for your code you can programmatically add those rather than pre-defining them in the main NIB. You can also load whole menus from a NIB just like with windows.

Step 2: Write an API to start & control your debugger

This is the API a client will call. Modify your debugger app's startup to call this API to test it.

Step 3: Convert project to a framework.

The framework will contain both the code and NIBs.

Step 4: Use framework in another app, call the API.

HTH

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot when I get the time. Do you know if a single application have 2 docks icons, 2 menu bars, 2 main windows etc. with a shared objc runtime?

Comment: For that you would have to build a real debugger, one which can access and control a *seperate* app - like lldb used by Xcode.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can go about doing that? For one, wouldn't SIP disable any attempts to meddle in another applications memory space?

Comment: How to write a debugger is not exactly an SO question! You could try looking at the [LLDB website](http://lldb.llvm.org), it is an open source project.